# Filters on top of table using sDom and columnFilter

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables

Is there an easy way to move the filters from the footer of the table to the head section using the `sDom` attribute?

Currently I am using this: `"sDom": 'WT<"clear"><"H"lfr>t<"F"ip>'` (using JQuery UI)

If i try moving the filter at the top using `sPlaceHolder` like this:

```
.columnFilter({sPlaceHolder: "head:before"});
```

I get my table to grow to the right, overlapping all my divs and creating a horizontal page scroll-bar.

**UPDATE 1**
I am using [this](http://jquery-datatables-column-filter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/index.html) column filter addon

**UPDATE 2**
My current initialisation code is this:

```
var oTable = $('#' + tblName).dataTable({
    "aaSorting": [[1, 'asc']],
    "bJQueryUI": true,
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "iDisplayLength": -1,
    "aLengthMenu": [
        [10, 25, 50, 100, 200, -1],
        [10, 25, 50, 100, 200, "All"]
    ],
    "sDom": 'WT<"clear"><"H"lfr>t<"F"ip>',
    "oColumnFilterWidgets": {
        "aiExclude": [0, 1, 2, 6,7,8]
    },
    "oTableTools": {
        "sSwfPath": "../js/TableTools/media/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
        ,
        "aButtons": [
            {
                "sExtends": "xls",
                "sTitle": "Results",
                "sButtonText": "Export to Xls",
                "mColumns": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5,6,7,8]
            },
            {
                "sExtends": "pdf",
                "sPdfOrientation": "landscape",
                "sTitle": "Results",
                "sButtonText": "Export to Pdf",
                 "mColumns": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5,6,7,8,9,10]
            }]
    }
}).columnFilter( );
```

And shows this as output :
[image]

When i try to use `{sPlaceHolder: "head:before"}` like this:

```
....    .columnFilter({sPlaceHolder: "head:before"});
```

it shows the following output:

[image]

Note/Problem: See how the entire table breaks my divs and overflows to the right, giving me a horizontal scrollbar at the bottom.

Comment: Dunno about the columnFilter, but in my yadcf plugin filters comes on top of the column by default http://yadcf-showcase.appspot.com/multiple_tables.html

Comment: hm... looks nice with some cool functionality, i ll give it a go sometime

Comment: I'm not sure which of the many columnfilter plugins you are using. Can you post a link to the one you want an answer to?

Comment: Hm, I am not sure if understand your question. Maybe you can add a screenshot or a drawing to show us what you want to achieve. Or use this Plunker to clarify and fork it back tom me? http://plnkr.co/edit/R0u6k8dsw7vwiilHILcU?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

In Line 115 of the plugin change this line:

```
var input = $('<input type="text" class="' + search_init + sCSSClass + '" value="' + inputvalue + '" rel="' + i + '"/>');
```

to:

```
var input = $('<input type="text" style="width:100%" class="' + search_init + sCSSClass + '" value="' + inputvalue + '" rel="' + i + '"/>');
```

This will set a forced width of 100% to the TEXT input field. Of course this has to be done with the other Inputs too. (RangeInput etc ...) I don't know if you use any in your table.

Maybe have a look at this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Gmzz6DxecK0p0Ve88YJb?p=preview) where I wrapped the whole table in a very narrow container div with 300px width. Now overlapping or scrollbars here!

Meanwhile I will try to find out if this can't be done with a simple css rule.

**Update:**
Yep, seems to work without patching the plugin with this css rule:

```
th input{
  width:100%;
}
```

[Look here (style.css)](http://plnkr.co/edit/V9JQjvUECXROqA9D8VDY?p=preview)

Please give some feedback if this is what you wanted.

Btw: Its a little bit annoying that this plugin starts sorting as soon as you focus an input :-\

**Another Update**

To get rid of the sorting, the most simplest way would be to set bSortable for the columns to false.

```
  $("#dt").dataTable({
    "bJQueryUI": true,
    "sDom": 'WT<"clear"><"H"lfr>t<"F"ip>',
    aoColumns: [{
      type: "text",
      bSortable: false
    }, {
      type: "text",
      bSortable: false
    }, {
      type: "text",
      bSortable: false
    }]
  }).columnFilter({
    sPlaceHolder: "head:before",
    aoColumns: [{
      type: "text"
    }, {
      type: "text"
    }, {
      type: "text"
    }]
  });
```

Hm, but maybe sorting is wanted because its a cool feature? I'll try to find another solution ... Please wait ...

Uh yeah, here's the [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/PvY4zwXYCU5UmeBteIam?p=preview)

**Update time again:**
Having both sorting and filtering can only be achieved by patching the plugin source.
Use the columnfilter.js script from [this updated Plunker as reference](http://plnkr.co/edit/hZxXu44n8a4OUia73XcA?p=preview)

Line 124 - 126:
Here I change the template so that both filtering icons and input box can be displayed in the header cell (took me a whole while to find that out!)

```
    th.wrapInner('<div style="display:table-cell;" class="filter_column filter_text" />');
    th.append('<div style="display:table-cell;position: relative;top:4px" class="DataTables_sort_icon css_right ui-icon ui-icon-carat-2-n-s">');
    th.wrapInner('<div style="display:table;width:100%">');
```

In lines 165 - 171 I react to click and focus and stop bubbling so the click and focus events don't reach the underlying header cell which fires sorting.

```
    input.click(function (e) {
      e.stopPropagation();

    });

    input.focus(function (e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
```

This works only for text filter right now. You might find a way, to add these changes to the other filter inputs too because I'll switch down my computer at work for today and head homeward.

Since we have a few days left for this, I'll be back to you tomorrow if you have further questions.
Please keep me informed about your progress or if you found an even better solution.

Good Luck!

Comment: Yeap! It works with css rules. On 100% i have some problems by with 80% looks great....

Comment: Now that i have implemented it , the sorting when clicking on the input looks REALLY annoying. Do you have a suggestion how can i get over this?

Comment: Added another update to my answer. I'll try to find a better way, but this will surely not work without patching the plugin code.

Comment: As i have set the width of the input now to 80%, there is still some room visible to the right of the input that would be nice to be used for sorting also on the th's with input

Comment: Another fine update is waiting for some fiddling :-)

Comment: in 13 hours you will be awarded also the bounty. Thanks